# Flag in the response to indicate a "guest" login

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Is there anything in the response that will indicate that the user was a "guest" while running the PayPal transaction?

Answer (score 0):

If it is PayPal payment, then we can see the buyer account email address
if it is guest checkout, then it shows "No Account" word in the transaction details